# Python Key logger with msvcrt

Tags: python, logging, key, keypress, keylistener

I am trying to create a python Keylistener for a self driving car using the msvcrt module. But it doesn't capture the Keys I press. Here's the Code:

```
if msvcrt.getwch() == 'w':
    keypresses.append(1)
elif msvcrt.getwch() == 's':
    keypresses.append(2)
elif msvcrt.getwch() == 'd':
    keypresses.append(3)
elif msvcrt.getwch() == 'a':
    keypresses.append(4)
elif msvcrt.getwch() == 'w'and'a':
    keypresses.append(5)
elif msvcrt.getwch() == 'w'and'd':
    keypresses.append(6)
elif msvcrt.getwch() == 's'and'a':
    keypresses.append(7)
elif msvcrt.getwch() == 's'and'd':
    keypresses.append(8)
else:
    keypresses.append(0)
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that you are checking for a new keypress in each if statement, rather than saving the keypress once and checking what that result is.
To save the keypress once, you should do this:

```
keypress = msvcrt.getwch()
```

and then check the value of keypress. i.e.:

```
if keypress == "a":
   print("The 'a' key has been pressed')
```

Comment: What is the issue then? Could you describe in more detail what the problem is?

Comment: The Program should append some number to the array "keypresses" when the W, A, S or D keys are pressed and 0 when something other happens. But it only appends 0, regardless if I press the W, A, S or D key. I hope this explanation helped.

Comment: Try `if keypress in ('W', 'w')` then. Sorry, but I don't have access to msvcrt on my system so I can't test that, but it would be the other issue, if anything.

Comment: Sorry I already switched to the Win32api and it worked. Thank you anyway.